# Why is Python's 'exec' behaving oddly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exec

Why does the following code work while the code after it breaks?

I'm not sure how to articulate my question in english, so I attached the smallest code I could come up with to highlight my problem.

(Context: I'm trying to create a terminal environment for python, but for some reason the namespaces seem to be messed up, and the below code seems to be the essence of my problem)

No errors:

```
d={}
exec('def a():b',d)
exec('b=None',d)
exec('a()',d)
```

Errors:

```
d={}
exec('def a():b',d)
d=d.copy()
exec('b=None',d)
d=d.copy()
exec('a()',d)
```

Comment: That's your hint to not use `exec` and `eval` ;-)

Comment: Tricky. Note that if you do the `exec` that defines `b` before the one that defines `a` then the 2nd version works. Or if you get rid of the 1st copy (but I guess you already know that). I'm still not quite sure why the copying messes stuff up, but I guess it's has something to do with the fact that `b` is a global

Answer (score 2):

It is because the `d` does not use the globals provided by `exec`; it uses the mapping to which it stored the reference in the first `exec`. While you set `'b'` in the new dictionary, you never set `b` in the globals of *that*  function.

```
>>> d={}
>>> exec('def a():b',d)
>>> exec('b=None',d)
>>> d['a'].__globals__ is d
True
>>> 'b' in d['a'].__globals__
True
```

vs

```
>>> d={}
>>> exec('def a():b',d)
>>> d = d.copy()
>>> exec('b=None',d)
>>> d['a'].__globals__ is d
False
>>> 'b' in d['a'].__globals__
False
```

---

If `exec` **didn't** work this way, then this too would fail:

### mod.py

```
b = None
def d():
    b
```

### main.py

```
from mod import d
d()
```

A function will remember the environment where it was first created.

---

It is not possible to change the dictionary that an existing function points to. You can either modify its globals explicitly, or you can make *another* function object altogether:

```
from types import FunctionType

def rebind_globals(func, new_globals):
    f = FunctionType(
        code=func.__code__,
        globals=new_globals,
        name=func.__name__,
        argdefs=func.__defaults__,
        closure=func.__closure__
    )
    f.__kwdefaults__ = func.__kwdefaults__
    return f


def foo(a, b=1, *, c=2):
    print(a, b, c, d)


# add __builtins__ so that `print` is found...    
new_globals = {'d': 3, '__builtins__': __builtins__}
new_foo = rebind_globals(foo, new_globals)
new_foo(a=0)
```

Comment: Thank you - this does help! Is there any way to go about injecting globals into a function? That way I could change the value of b in main.py in a way that b() would respond to

Comment: @RyanBurgert added